# java streams filter and include

Tags: java, stream

I have a array of words here.

I want to get all words :

1. more that 5 chars long and
2. all words starting with a 'i' rregardless of length.

How do I achieve the second criteria?

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("art", "again", "orphanage", "forest", "cat", "bat");
List<String> result = words.stream()
        .filter(word -> word.length() > 5)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word));
```

My expected output should be `art again orphanage forest`

Comment: word.startsWith("a") || word.length() > 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Predicate<String> isStartWithA = word -> word.startsWith("a");
Predicate<String> fiveChar = word -> word.length() > 5;
List<String> words=Arrays.asList("art", "again", "orphanage", "forest", "cat", "bat");
List<String> result = words.stream() .filter(isStartWithA.or(fiveChar)) 
.collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(word -> System.out.println(word))
```